# GoogleMap API: выявление всех точек внутри выделенной области

Tags: google-maps-api, javascript, php

Здравствуйте. Вполне возможно, что заголовок не очень информативен, попытаюсь объяснить более детально суть вопроса.
   Существует некая База Данных, в которой есть координаты точек на карте. Эти точки необходимо вывести на карту. Собственно первый вопрос:

**1) Как все эти координаты вывести на карту? Какой метод лучше использовать?**

Теперь проблема №2:

**2) Необходимо по-умолчанию задать некий полигон (выделенную область), в котором будут отображаться точки, если таковы есть в зоне этой области. Также необходимо реализовать возможность изменения размеров данного полигона. Все точки вне области полигона должны быть скрытыми, пока полигон не расширят и они не окажутся в зоне видимости.**

Я понимаю, что задача скорее всего, чрезвычайно объемная, многогранная и сложная, но буду рад любым подсказкам, с чего начинать, куда смотреть, что читать и тестировать. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-marker-lasso-search-tool.htm

вот, собственно, и ответ на мой вопрос. может, кому-то пригодится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужны указатели на карте, то почитайте про Marker в документации у гугла. Там можно указать расположение этих маркеров по координатам.

Для второй проблемы могу предложить следующий вариант. Определяете по координатам, какие из точек ближе к правому, левому, верхнему и нижнему краям, а затем располагаете обзор таким образом, чтобы все крайние точки вошли. Думаю здесь поможет Zoom для карты.

Ну это так, чисто теоритически. За практикой надо лезть в [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=ru)